# Numpy collapse columns according to list

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

In `NumPy`, I have a `d x n` array `A` and a list `L` of length `n`, describing where I want each column of `A` to end up in matrix `B`. The idea is that column `i` of matrix `B` is the `sum` of all columns of `A` for which the corresponding value in `L` is `i`.

I can do this with a `for` loop:

```
A = np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)
L = [0,1,2,1,1]
n_cols = 3
B = np.zeros((len(A), n_cols)) 
# assume I know the desired number of columns, 
# which is also one more than the maximum value of L
for i, a in enumerate(A.T):
    B[:, L[i]] += a
```

I was wondering if there a way to do this by slicing array `A` (or in some otherwise vectorized manner)?

Comment: Do you think you could post a complete example? (i.e. a [mcve]) It would help if we could see the effect of this code on small matrices and an example of a list `L` too.

Comment: @Praveen I filled out the example a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sum-reducing/collapsing the columns off `A` using `L` for selecting those columns. Also, you are updating the columns of output array based on the uniqueness of `L` elems.

Thus, you can use [`np.add.reduceat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) for a vectorized solution, like so -

```
sidx = L.argsort()
col_idx, grp_start_idx = np.unique(L[sidx],return_index=True)
B_out = np.zeros((len(A), n_cols))
B_out[:,col_idx] = np.add.reduceat(A[:,sidx],grp_start_idx,axis=1)
```

---

Runtime test -

```
In [129]: def org_app(A,n_cols):
     ...:     B = np.zeros((len(A), n_cols)) 
     ...:     for i, a in enumerate(A.T):
     ...:         B[:, L[i]] += a
     ...:     return B
     ...: 
     ...: def vectorized_app(A,n_cols):
     ...:     sidx = L.argsort()
     ...:     col_idx, grp_start_idx = np.unique(L[sidx],return_index=True)
     ...:     B_out = np.zeros((len(A), n_cols))
     ...:     B_out[:,col_idx] = np.add.reduceat(A[:,sidx],grp_start_idx,axis=1)
     ...:     return B_out
     ...: 

In [130]: # Setup inputs with an appreciable no. of cols & lesser rows
     ...: # so as that memory bandwidth to work with huge number of 
     ...: # row elems doesn't become the bottleneck
     ...: d,n_cols = 10,5000
     ...: A = np.random.rand(d,n_cols)
     ...: L = np.random.randint(0,n_cols,(n_cols,))
     ...: 

In [131]: np.allclose(org_app(A,n_cols),vectorized_app(A,n_cols))
Out[131]: True

In [132]: %timeit org_app(A,n_cols)
10 loops, best of 3: 33.3 ms per loop

In [133]: %timeit vectorized_app(A,n_cols)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.87 ms per loop
```

As the number of rows become comparable with the number of cols in `A`, the high memory bandwidth requirements for the vectorized approach would offset any noticeable speedup from it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this iteration on ``B` the same (not tested)?

```
 for I in range(B.shape[1]):
       B[:, I] = A[:, L==I].sum(axis=1)
```

The number loops will be fewer.  But more importantly it may give other vectorization insights.

(edit) on testing, this works, but is much slower.

+========

`scipy.sparse` does column sum with matrix product with a matrix of ones.  Can we do the same here?  Make `C` array with 1s in the right columns

```
def my2(A,L):
    n_cols = L.shape[0]
    C = np.zeros((n_cols,n_cols),int)
    C[np.arange(n_cols), L] = 1
    return A.dot(C)
```

This is 7x faster than your loop, and slightly faster than `@Divakars` `reduceat` code.

==========

```
In [126]: timeit vectorized_app(A,L)
The slowest run took 8.16 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 99.7 µs per loop
In [127]: timeit val2 = my2(A,L)
The slowest run took 10.46 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 81.6 µs per loop
In [128]: timeit org1(A,n_cols)
1000 loops, best of 3: 623 µs per loop
In [129]: d,n_cols
Out[129]: (10, 100)
```